# Unable to activate Windows Store App with error The app didn't start in the required time

Tags: uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

Unable to start uwp in Win10.

Several files need to be run in the startup phase of this uwp, but a single file that takes a long time to run can cause this error. In addition, the program runs fine in debug mode.

So, I wonder if this error was caused by startup timeout or something else? If the former what is the time limit to start? How do I fix it?

Comment: Always include the error description as text and paste the image as part of your question itself (Avoid external Links)

Comment: If you have a lot file need to be load, you could try to  display a splash screen for [more time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-a-customized-splash-screen).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already have a **store package** in your system and Trying to debug with a new package. Kindly **uninstall** if your application is already installed and then try to Debug it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried, but I still get this error